# Sort array by financial month from April to March using react native array sort function

Tags: react-native

array to be sorted :

[
{
"Title": "Jan",
"month": 1,
},
{
"Title": "Feb",
"month": 2,
},
{
"Title": "Mar",
"month": 3,
},
{
"Title": "Apr",
"month": 4,
},
{
"Title": "May",
"month": 5,
},
{
"Title": "Jun",
"month": 6,
},
{
"Title": "Jul",
"month": 7,
},
{
"Title": "Aug",
"month": 8,
},
{
"Title": "Sep",
"month": 9,
},
{
"Title": "Oct",
"month": 10,
},
{
"Title": "Nov",
"month": 11,
},
{
"Title": "Dec",
"month": 12,
}
]

Expected outcome :
[  { "Title": "Apr", "month": 4, }, { "Title": "May", "month": 5, }, { "Title": "Jun", "month": 6, }, { "Title": "Jul", "month": 7, }, { "Title": "Aug", "month": 8, }, { "Title": "Sep", "month": 9, }, { "Title": "Oct", "month": 10, }, { "Title": "Nov", "month": 11, }, { "Title": "Dec", "month": 12, }, { "Title": "Jan", "month": 1, }, { "Title": "Feb", "month": 2, }, { "Title": "Mar", "month": 3, } ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved using array sort function.**

var mainArray = [ { "Title": "Jan", "month": 1, }, { "Title": "Feb", "month": 2, }, { "Title": "Mar", "month": 3, }, { "Title": "Apr", "month": 4, }, { "Title": "May", "month": 5, }, { "Title": "Jun", "month": 6, }, { "Title": "Jul", "month": 7, }, { "Title": "Aug", "month": 8, }, { "Title": "Sep", "month": 9, }, { "Title": "Oct", "month": 10, }, { "Title": "Nov", "month": 11, }, { "Title": "Dec", "month": 12, } ]

var monthNames = [
"Apr",
"May",
"Jun",
"Jul",
"Aug",
"Sep",
"Oct",
"Nov",
"Dec",
"Jan",
"Feb",
"Mar",
]

mainArray.sort((a,b) => { return monthNames.indexOf(a.Title) - monthNames.indexOf(b.Title)})

**Output :**
[ { "Title": "Apr", "month": 4, }, { "Title": "May", "month": 5, }, { "Title": "Jun", "month": 6, }, { "Title": "Jul", "month": 7, }, { "Title": "Aug", "month": 8, }, { "Title": "Sep", "month": 9, }, { "Title": "Oct", "month": 10, }, { "Title": "Nov", "month": 11, }, { "Title": "Dec", "month": 12, }, { "Title": "Jan", "month": 1, }, { "Title": "Feb", "month": 2, }, { "Title": "Mar", "month": 3, } ]

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you have to execute two conditions like in first you have to check greater then 3 ( logic is depands on you) , and in second greater and equal to 1 and lesser and equal to 3 ,

hope this will work ,